# Cannot accept meeting invitations from Google Calendar sent to + subaddressed

Tags: gmail, google-calendar

I frequently use subaddressing (or plus addressing) when I give out my Gmail address, e.g., **name+stackexchange@gmail.com**.

However, when I receive event invitations to such an address Google Calendar prevents me from accepting them. Instead I see an error message saying that I can't forward invitations.

How can I workaround this?

Comment: What happens if you forward the invitations to your main address?

Comment: I recently accepted an invite with subaddressing, so I assume this particular issue has been fixed. HOWEVER, the event does not show up in my calendar, nor is it possible to add a subaddressed gmail address as an alternate email. I guess these weird edge cases are hard to predict.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you can get the person who sent the invitation to re-send it to your "normal" Gmail address, I think your only option is to work with the attached `invite.ics` file.

From the email message invitation, simply click to download to save it locally. Then go into your Google Calendar and click the down arrow next to "Other calendars". Choose "Import calendar". Select the file you just downloaded. You should now have the event in your calendar.

This is obviously sub-optimal. There's several extra steps and the event won't automatically be updated if there are changes.

Comment: Does this allow to reply with attending?

Comment: @dman: Well, no, that would be one of the problems with this method: no way to reply.